# Finding Primary Key column(s) in View

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm building prog logic which goes through all my tables and views in MySQL schema and creates PHP objects for DB persistence. My DAO layer. These objects have CRUD methods but Finder methods as well. In INFORMATION_SCHEMA there's information what column is PK for each table, but not for Views. I need to dynamically find what column is kind a PK in View.

Let's say that we have simple one-to-many relation (e.g. ProdTypes and Products)

- ProdTypes [ProdTypeId,ProdTypeName] <-- ProdTypeId = PK
- Products [ProdId,ProdName,ProdTypeId] <-- ProdId = PK, ProdTypeId = FK

And a view as simple SELECT of two joined tables:

```
SELECT p.prodid,p.prodname,t.prodtypename
FROM products p
JOIN prodtypes t ON t.prodtypeid=p.prodtypeid
```

When one creates such a view, MySQL will say in INFORMATION_SCHEMA that this view does not have primary key(s) (OK, because it's view). But we know that `ProdId` is column uniquely defining records in this view! So although it is not officially PK, this column has this function in view and can be assumed as PK. One can create `findByProdId()` method which will return always 1 record (or zero if not found)!

The question is how to find out what column(s) in view uniquely define(!s) records in it!? Or what is (unofficial) primary key in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not extract or search for the primary key of a view. A view can be a complex join, so you would determine the primary key of each table involved and not necessarily the selected fields are part of the primary key. The only time you can determine the primary key in a view is only when the view query includes a single table and only makes sense if the selected fields include those that make up the primary key.

On the other hand, when you execute a sql statement in PHP, you always have access to metadata. Metadata is an object for each field. The object has properties such as:

```
function mysqlMetadata(& $db) {
    $id     = $db->Query_ID;
    $META = new stdClass();

    $count = @mysql_num_fields($id);

    $META->cols = array();

    for($ix=0;$ix<$count;$ix++) {
        $col            = @mysql_field_name  ($id, $ix); 
        $type           = @mysql_field_type  ($id, $ix);
        $standarType    = MetaStandardType("MYSQL",$type);

        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ] = new stdClass();
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"type"}   = $standarType;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"type_raw"} = $type;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"size"}       = @mysql_field_len   ($id, $ix);
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"precision"}= 0;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"scale"}      = 0;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"is_null"}  = 1;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"flags"}  = @mysql_field_flags ($id, $ix);
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"is_null"}        = !(MYSQLI_NOT_NULL_FLAG & $property->flags) ;// decbin($property->flags ); //1;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"primary_key"}    = !(!(MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG & $property->flags)) ;// decbin($property->flags ); //1;
        $META->colsbyname[ "$col" ]->{"auto_increment"} = !(!(MYSQLI_AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG & $property->flags)) ;// decbin($property->flags ); //1;

    }

    return $META;

}
```